# tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().time() is not in my timezone, how to configure timezone offset?

Tags: python, timezone, tornado, timezone-offset

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().time() gives Zulu. How do I get my time regarding timezone to add some seconds as deadline in IOLoop.add_timeout(deadline) so timeout triggers in future correctly?

My time is +1h and it does not trigger because the 60s i IOLoop.add_timeout(60) are already passed. But during summer I have +2h so I have to add my timezone-offset correctly during summer and wintertime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately that isn't timezone-related problem. What confused you is probably *deadline* vs *delay* terminology. Thankfully the [`IOLoop.add_timeout`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html)'s documentation is pretty clear,

> deadline may be a number denoting a time (on the same scale as IOLoop.time, normally time.time), or a datetime.timedelta object for a deadline relative to the current time. Since Tornado 4.0, call_later is a more convenient alternative for the relative case since it does not require a timedelta object.

A code like:

```
IOLoop.current().add_timeout(60, some_func)
```

actually means to run a function 60 seconds after unix epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970) not from now (`time.time()`). so it riggers immediately.

As docs states, you may either

- pass delay as a timedelta object

  ```
  import datetime
  IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=60), some_func)
  ```
- or use [`IOloop.call_Later()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.call_later)

  ```
  IOLoop.current().call_later(delay=60, some_func)
  ```